# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid ruby on rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deploy on heroku and running command heroku open. It opens in browser fine. But when I click on a signup button it stopped and give following heroku logs. It's working on local server perfectly. But I also want to run on heroku server. This is example of [http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:signin_success](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec%3asignin_success)

```
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/new" for 122.179.134.45 at 2012-05-11 05:24:58 -0700
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 37ms
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]: :             SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:              WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:               FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:                AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:              ORDER BY a.attnum
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 heroku[router]: GET demoapp3708.heroku.com/users/new dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=44ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
2012-05-11T12:24:58+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `new'
```

Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
#We’ll use the state-of-the-art hash function called bcrypt to irreversibly encrypt the password    to form the password hash.
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'pg', '0.13.2'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6'
end


group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'guard-spork', '0.3.2'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'    
  #gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end

group :assets do
  # gem 'execjs'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'  
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end 

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end  
end
```

After heroku run rake db:migrate

```
 PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
 : ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "password_digest" character varying(255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you deploy this code? Are database migrations part of your deployment script.

Else you will have to run them manually using

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Oh dexter! its you! Thanks for your reply. Let me try. It's giving following errors:

Comment: Do I have to do db:migrate each time I modify the Gemfile file? I did it before I changed the file but after changing the file and deployed the project I got the error and had to run the command above.